# Android: How do you set default view attributes?

Tags: android, view, styles, default

I have multiple buttons that all have the same textSize, layout_width, etc. and I do not want to copy and paste these attributes over and over as it makes for hard to edit code. In other words, I am looking to take many of these:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button_normal"
    android:text="@string/button1"
    android:textSize="50sp" />
```

And instead be able to use a preset button (where the layout_width, layout_height, layout_weight, background, and textSize are all set to the above values, by default):

```
<PresetButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:text="@string/button1" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use styles.

[Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Example:

In: `res/values/styles.xml`

```
<style name="Numbers">
  <item name="android:inputType">number</item>
</style>
```

Use like this:

```
<EditText
    style="@style/Numbers" />
```

Comment: thank you! I just didn't know what to call this as I am new to Android development

Answer (score 1):

You can use styles.xml to create a style, then you can apply that styling to each button.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 1):

in your values -> style.xml file put the xml attribute

```
 <style name="buttonConfirm" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15dip</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>

</style>
```

and in your layout call it by this xml

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="@style/buttonConfirm"
    android:text="Button"
    />
```